# Setting the date for DatePicker in another class?

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
//inside New_Entry.h
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *timePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDatePicker *timePicker;

//inside New_Entry.m
@synthesize timePicker;

//inside AppDelegate.m
#import "New_Entry.h"
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
NSDate *todayDate;
todayDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
New_Entry.timePicker.date = todayDate;
[todayDate release];
}
```

Got an error in "New_Entry.timePicker.date = todayDate;"
How do I update the timePicker.date to now whenever the app becomes active? Whats the difference between "DidBecomeActive" and "DidEnterForeground"?

Edit:

```
In AppDelegate (applicationWillEnterForeground)
New_Entry *new_Entry_instance = [[New_Entry alloc]init];
new_Entry_instance.timePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fails because you are not calling timePicker.date on a valid instance of the New_Entry class.

To make this work you would have to do something like this:

```
New_Entry *new_entry_instance = [[New_Entry alloc] init];
new_entry_instance.timePicker.date = todayDate;
```

If you are unsure of why this is the way to do it then please ask.

Comment: also, i don't think calling [[NSDate alloc] init] sets todayDate to an actual value.  if you want the current date, try:    new_entry_instance.timePicker.date = [NSDate date];

Comment: @pistachionut - Very true, nice catch.

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the project, but I am guessing that your UIDatePicker is never hooked up in Interface Builder. Also, where are you instantiating new_entry_instance?

Comment: i really appreciate your help. yes it's hooked up, the whole app is running except for this. i added the new code above.

Comment: The the problem (I think) is that you are messaging the wrong instance of New_Entry. How did you hook up timePicker if you are creating new_entry_instance in code?

Comment: i dont quite understand this part. the timePicker is already hooked in the interface builder and working in New_Entry. do i still have to hook it in the "instance" version? If you dont mind, can I mail you my code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm knee deep in stuff right now. I can though that you are confused about object oriented programming. You say that timePicker is hooked up but I bet if you do NSLog(@"%@", new_Entry_instance.timePicker) it will come up as nil. The reason is that you don't create new_Entry_instance until your applicationDidBecomeActive method. Whatever you hooked up in IB isn't really hooked up. Sure, it is probably there and you can spin around the dates but it isn't hooked up in the sense that it is connected to your new_Entry_instance.

Comment: hey you're right! It turned out as null. So how do I hook it?

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but I think you would really benefit from some tutorials. Picking up a new framework and paradigm can be really tough. This is a great site: http://cocoadevcentral.com/ Go through the tutorials and you'll have a much better grasp of what is going on. If I help you fix this one problem, sure, that problem will be solved, but you'll come up against something else very soon that is, quite honestly, a core competency for building iPhone apps.

Comment: thanks but I would appreciate if you can help me out for now. i've been looking around for the past one hour and still helpless. i need the code tomorrow morning :(